# Is there an any way to make report result uft has screen capture in every steps?

Tags: ui-automation, hp-uft

So, I have problem when I try to use the generate document (doc format) from UFT. Because there is not available screen capture for every steps.

[image]
Below im attached the generate document from uft and my screen capture setting.

Comment: That setting should capture screenshots for every step. When you say generate a document, do you mean from the run results viewer? or the html report?  - Can you please share what your output report looks like?

Comment: Yes, it from Run Result Viewer Report. 
[Doc Generate from UFT Screen Capture] https://ibb.co/60J9Y8b
as you can see in picture, there is some step do not have screenshot.

Comment: I got in contact with support who spoke to the Dev. It's a known bug in uft - screen capture in Web only and works with IE.  You'll need to use the html report which captures the images and convert to your needed doematy on your own